# sed and regex to replace ',' except inside a string

Tags: regex, sed

I have an input of the following schema

```
10,0,'string1_string2,_string3','',8,0,0,0.59,'20140101205216','20140128074836',584266915,5934
```

and  I would like to replace all comma "`,`" characters with tabs using sed. The constraint is to not replace "`,`" inside text strings (i.e the comma in `'string1_string2,_string3'` should not be replaced with tab). A regex to do this is ,(?!,_).

However the following sed does not work. I've tried all escaping permutations too.

```
sed s/",\(\?\!,_\)"/"\t"/g
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would use a Perl program to read the line in, break it up according to the CSV fields, modify the field in question, then rebuild the line.  Dealing with structured data in an unstructured way is a long-term nightmare.

Comment: Thanks Johanthan, and everyone else below. Yes, you are quite right. I have had many nightmares. I have a solution as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.9.1, you can use:

```
sed -E -e "s/('[^']*'|[^,]*),/\1X/g"
```

except that you'd replace the X with an actual tab.  For your input line, that yields:

```
10X0X'string1_string2,_string3'X''X8X0X0X0.59X'20140101205216'X'20140128074836'X584266915X5934
```

which has X's where you want tabs.  With GNU `sed`, you can use `-r` in place of `-E` (though it also recognizes `-E`).  Mac `sed` will not expand `\t` to a tab; GNU `sed` will.  With Bash, you can use the ANSI-C Quoting mechanism to have the shell embed a tab in the string passed to `sed`:

```
sed -E -e "s/('[^']*'|[^,]*),/\1"$'\t'"/g"
```

Without the extended regular expressions (activated by `-r` or `-E`), it isn't worth trying in `sed`; use `awk` instead.

The regex looks for *either* a single quote followed by zero or more non-quotes and a single quote *or* zero or more non-commas, followed by a comma, and replaces it with what was remembered as the either/or string and a 'tab' (using X to represent tab because it is more visible).

---

[devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648375/sed-and-regex-to-replace-except-inside-a-string/21648613?noredirect=1#comment32719558_21648613) that the answer above replaces the comma in a string at the end of a line.  There's a workaround for that:

```
sed -E -e "s/('[^']*'|[^,]*)(,|$)/\1"$'\t'"/g; s/"$'\t'"$//"
```

The `s///g` before the semicolon adds a tab to the end of each line; the `s///` after the semicolon removes the tab that was just added.

Comment: +1; on OSX, splice in `$'\t'` to create a tab char. (works analogously with other control chars., e.g., `$'\n'`). It looks awkward (no awk pun intended), but it works: `sed -E -e "s/('[^']*'|[^,]*),/\1"$'\t'"/g"`

Comment: Yes, that would certainly work, using Bash and the [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism, but it is the shell handling the `\t` and not `sed`. (I know you know; I'm making sure others reading later know too.)  Using control-V control-I (or tab) also works.  With GNU `sed`, `sed` itself handles the `\t` to tab translation.

Comment: I'm afraid that this might break if the strings ends with quoted text, e.g. `a,'b,c'`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well put - thanks for introducing me to the _name_ of the `$'...'` feature.

Comment: @devnull: well spotted…yes, it will replace commas in strings that end a line.  At first glance, replacing `,` with `(,|$)` would help, but that adds a tab at the end of the line which is unlikely to be wanted. Dealing with that in `sed` may be more trouble than it is worth.  I'm going to need to meditate on the solution; I'm drawing a blank at the moment.

Comment: Right, this is easier to deal with using perl or awk.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest take Perl's help if available because of availability of **lookarounds**:

```
s="10,0,'string1_string2,_string3','',8,0,0,0.59,'20140101205216','20140128074836',584266915,5934"

perl -pe "s/,(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)/\t/g" <<< "$s"

10\t0\t'string1_string2,_string3'\t''\t8\t0\t0\t0.59\t'20140101205216'\t'20140128074836'\t584266915\t5934
```

PS: Showing `\t` only for readability purpose.

Comment: +1; it works, but my brain is still hurting from trying to understand: 
- Due to the lookahead assertion `(?=...)`, matching is performed through the *end* of the line for *every* `,` found.
- The entire expression in parentheses is the lookahead expression that matches only if the preceding `,` is NOT inside a single-quoted string. - It does so by looking for *pairs* of quotes - the implication is that if the remaining quotes on the line, if any, are NOT paired, the `,` at hand must be *inside* a quoted string.
- Net effect: only `,` chars. outside of quoted strings are matched and replaced.

Comment: Yes it appears little tricky but what it does is to make sure there are always even number of single quotes (0,2,4,6...) following a comma. The lookahead is doing just that (see `{2}` part).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html):

```
perl -MText::ParseWords -n -l -e 'print join("\t", parse_line(",", 1, $_));' filename
```

For your input, it'd result in:

```
10      0       'string1_string2,_string3'      ''      8       0       0       0.59    '20140101205216'        '20140128074836'        584266915       5934
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work if I understand your question correctly:

```
sed -E 's/,([^_])/\t\1/g'
```

Output:

```
10  0   'string1_string2,_string3'  ''  8   0   0   0.59    '20140101205216'    '20140128074836'    584266915   5934
```

Comment: This works on the given data because of the coincidence that the comma in the string is followed by an underscore and none of the other commas is followed by an underscore.  It doesn't handle variants, such as `'string1, string2, string3',_abc_` all that well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know, but there’s no requirement to handle all variants in the question. Peyman suggested `sed s/",\(\?\!,_\)"/"\t"/g` which is about replacing `,_` -> `\t`. I’m a little confused what he’s really asking for. If it should work for all other variants, then my answer is useless of course.